# store line in linked list (c)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I think that I am having some issues with how linked lists work, please bear in mind that I am not an expert with C and that I have not worked with linked lists before.

I'm trying to take a text file with a list of things and store it in a linked list. I have the following code right now:

```
typedef struct linked_list {
    struct linked_list *next_ptr;
    char name;
    float price1;
    float price2;
}linked_list;

struct linked_list *first_ptr;
char name_temp;

int writeList(void) {
    // read input files
    FILE *sh_list;
    sh_list=fopen("case1/shoppingList.dat", "rw");
    if (sh_list == NULL) {
        perror("Cannot open file, you seem to have something mixed up...");
        exit(8);
    }

    struct linked_list *current_ptr;
    current_ptr = first_ptr;

    while ((fscanf(sh_list, "%s", &name_temp)) !=EOF) {
        next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
        strcpy(name, name_temp);
        //move to next node and complete the same task
    }
};
```

I stopped at the //move... because I am struggling to get the code correct - my IDE is giving me errors. Similarly, I can't get it to read the variable "name" which I need to do in order to copy the string to the node.

Comment: Always specify what errors you're getting.

Comment: The error I'm looking to fix is that it says "next_ptr" is an unidentified variable in the function writeList. Beyond that, I was looking for some advice for the right direction to move to get this thing stored in a linked list.

Comment: You probably need an array for the name: `char name[36];` or thereabouts (choose your size).  This needs to be in the structure; you also reference a variable `name` in the function but provide no definition of it; you also have `char name_temp;` which should (a) be inside the function and (b) should also be an array.  You should specify the size of the array minus one in the format (`"%35s"` for example).

Comment: Don't put semi-colons after the brace at the end of a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting next_ptr as undeclared because you have not delcared it.

Your code should look something like this ...

```
linked_list   *next_ptr;
char          name_temp[MAX_SIZE];

while ((fscanf(sh_list, "%s", &name_temp)) !=EOF) {
         next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
         strcpy(next_ptr->name, name_temp);
         next_ptr->next_ptr = first_ptr;
         first_ptr = next_ptr;
}
```

You should also make the declaration of name in linked list to be:

```
char      name[MAX_SIZE];
```

Comment: this helped a lot, that took care of all of the errors I was getting - thanks :). I'm going to keep plugging away, but in theory this will store each line in the linked list?

also, where is the best place to actually read about linked lists and their inner workings, clearly I'm not quite understanding them as well as I should be (I'm aware of this)

Answer (score 0):

In your `fscanf` statement you specify that you're inputting a string, `%s`, but `name_temp` has type `char`. You're going to have to change it to a `char` array, like so:

```
char name_temp[100];
```

You'll have to make the array sufficiently big for your purposes. You'll also have to change the type of `name`:

```
char name[100];
```

The error you are getting is because `name` and `next_ptr` are part of the struct `linked_list` but you you have to create an instantiation of `linked_list` to access `name`. In your case, you have the `current_ptr` so you should change it to:

```
current_ptr->next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
strcpy(current_ptr->name, name_tmp);
```

Comment: do you have any idea why it's telling me that next_ptr is undeclared?

Comment: @SoFly For the same reason as why `name` was undeclared. `next_ptr` is part of a struct and you have to create an instantiation of the struct to access a copy of `next_ptr`.

Comment: they're still undeclared, so I need to create some kind of reference inside of the function to access the struct's variables?

Comment: Because `next_ptr` is not declared as a variable.  If you want to reference an element of the structure, you have to have a structure to reference:  `linked_list item; item.next_ptr = malloc(...);`.  Even with that fixed, you probably have some chicken-and-egg issues to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `strcpy(current_ptr->name, name_temp);`

You are trying to refer to the name variable in the structure, which needs to be accessed through the current_ptr.

so similarly it should be `current_ptr->next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));`

To access variable in a structure, you need to use the `.` operator. When you are using a pointer to a structure, then you access its variables using the `->`operator.